# how to use async/await inside promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, promise

I want to use async/await inside this promise.allSettled to convert currency by fetching some api or databased stored currency rates.

like i want to use await here like this, but not sure where to put async.

```
arrcars["price_client"] = await forexService.convertCurrency(item.regular_price, "EUR", userCurrency);
```

I have posted my entire code. need some guidance here.

> This is controller

```
    const httpStatus = require('http-status');
    const pick = require('../utils/pick');
    const catchAsync = require('../utils/catchAsync');
    const async = require('async');
    const axios = require('axios');
    const { talixoService } = require('../services');
    const { iwayService } = require('../services');
    const { forexService } = require('../services');
    
        const searchCars = function (req, res) {
            const talixoData = talixoService.findTalixoCars(req.body) //call talixo api in services
            const iwayData = iwayService.findiWayCars(req.body) //call iwaytransfers api in services
        
            if (req.query.usercurrency) {
                var userCurrency = req.query.usercurrency;
            } else {
                var userCurrency = "INR";
            }
        
            return Promise.allSettled([talixoData, iwayData]).then(([restalixo, resiway]) => {
                const taxiresults = [];
                if (restalixo.status === "fulfilled") {
                    //console.log(restalixo.value.data);
                    if (restalixo.value.data.taxis.length) {
                        restalixo.value.data.taxis.forEach(function (item) {
                            arrcars = {};
                            arrcars["carname"] = item.car_model;
                            arrcars["originprice"] = item.regular_price;
                            arrcars["price_client"] = forexService.convertCurrency(item.regular_price, "EUR", userCurrency);
                            arrcars["discountprice_client"] = forexService.convertCurrency(item.discount_price, "EUR", userCurrency);
                            arrcars["packageId"] = item.id;
                            arrcars["image"] = item.image_url;
                            arrcars["freewaittime"] = item.included_waiting_time;
                            arrcars["maxluggage"] = item.luggage;
                            arrcars["maxpassengers"] = item.seats;
                            arrcars["discountprice"] = item.discount_price;
                            arrcars["vehicletype"] = item.vehicle_type;
                            arrcars["vendor"] = "Talixo";
                            arrcars["vehicleremarks"] = "Or Similar";
                            taxiresults.push(arrcars);
                        });
                    }
                    if (restalixo.value.data.limousines.length) {
                        restalixo.value.data.limousines.forEach(function (item) {
                            arrcars = {};
                            arrcars["carname"] = item.car_model;
                            arrcars["originprice"] = item.regular_price;
                            arrcars["price_client"] = forexService.convertCurrency(item.regular_price, "EUR", userCurrency);
                            arrcars["discountprice_client"] = forexService.convertCurrency(item.discount_price, "EUR", userCurrency);
                            arrcars["packageId"] = item.id;
                            arrcars["image"] = item.image_url;
                            arrcars["freewaittime"] = item.included_waiting_time;
                            arrcars["maxluggage"] = item.luggage;
                            arrcars["maxpassengers"] = item.seats;
                            arrcars["discountprice"] = item.discount_price;
                            arrcars["vehicletype"] = item.vehicle_type;
                            arrcars["vendor"] = "Talixo";
                            arrcars["vehicleremarks"] = "Or Similar";
                            taxiresults.push(arrcars);
                        });
                    }
                }
                //iwaytransfers supplier data
                if (resiway.status === "fulfilled") {
                    //console.log(resiway.value.data);
                    if (resiway.value.data.result.length) {
                        resiway.value.data.result.forEach(function (item) {
                            var imgsrc = "https://iwayex.com/images/cars/";
                            arrcars = {};
                            arrcars["carname"] = item.car_class.models[0];
                            arrcars["originprice"] = item.price;
                            arrcars["price_client"] = forexService.convertCurrency(item.price, "EUR", userCurrency);
                            arrcars["discountprice_client"] = forexService.convertCurrency(item.price, "EUR", userCurrency);
                            arrcars["packageId"] = item.price_uid;
                            arrcars["image"] = imgsrc + item.car_class.photo;
                            arrcars["freewaittime"] = item.allowable_time;
                            arrcars["maxluggage"] = "";
                            arrcars["maxpassengers"] = item.car_class.capacity;
                            arrcars["discountprice"] = item.price;
                            arrcars["vehicletype"] = item.vehicle_type;
                            arrcars["vendor"] = "iway Transfers";
                            arrcars["vehicleremarks"] = "Or Similar";
                            taxiresults.push(arrcars);
                        });
                    }
                }
        
                if (taxiresults.length) {
                    sortedresult = taxiresults.sort(function (a, b) {
                        return a.discountprice - b.discountprice;
                    });
                    res.status(200).send(sortedresult)
                }else{
                    res.status(200).send({})
                }
            });
        }

module.exports = {
    searchCars
}
```

> this is the result sample i am getting.

```
{
carname: "Toyota Prius"
discountprice: 27.5
discountprice_client: {}
freewaittime: 45
image: "https://static.talixo.de/images/vehicles/economy.png"
maxluggage: 3
maxpassengers: 3
originprice: 27.5
packageId: "16021"
price_client: {}
vehicleremarks: "Or Similar"
vehicletype: "limo"
vendor: "Talixo"
}
```

here the problem is,
i expect

```
discountprice_client: Converted Number,
```

but i am getting blank object there as can be seen in above result sample.
i have been using this in another function with async await, then it works fine. but in this case, i am not sure how to put async/await.

> this is inside

forex.service.js

```
    const convertCurrency = async (amount, basecurrency, reqCurrency) => {
        if (basecurrency === reqCurrency) {
            let result = Math.round(amount) + ' ' + reqCurrency;
            return result;
        } else {
            const reqForexData = await getForexbyISO(reqCurrency);
            const baseForexData = await getForexbyISO(basecurrency);
            const amountInUSD = amount / baseForexData.forexRate;
            const amountInreqC = amountInUSD * reqForexData.forexRate;
            let result = Math.round(amountInreqC) + ' ' + reqCurrency;
            return result;
        }
    }

module.exports = {
    convertCurrency
}
```

Comment: JS doesn't allow top level awaits. However, typescript does. If using TS is not an option, you can use IIFE with the async code inside

Comment: @kanuos JS does, in ES modules, and TS only does if it's emitting to such a format.

Comment: OP didn't specify the problem

Comment: @KonradLinkowski i have updated my question with exact problem.

Comment: Not part of your question, but forex.service.js calls `getForexbyISO` twice in serial. You might want to get both promises (i.e. don't use `await`) and then do `Promise.all([reqForexDataPromise, baseForexDataPromise]).then(([reqForexData, baseForexData]) => ...)` so that it's done in parallel instead. Same for the function that `searchCars` passes to array.forEach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
// notice the `async` before `function`
resiway.value.data.result.forEach(async function (item) {
  // ...
  arrcars = {};
  arrcars["price_client"] = await forexService.convertCurrency(item.price, "EUR", userCurrency);
  arrcars["discountprice_client"] = await forexService.convertCurrency(item.price, "EUR", userCurrency);
  // ...
});
```

But it can lead to unexpected behaviours

I would do this

```
// add missing `async`
return Promise.allSettled([talixoData, iwayData]).then(async ([restalixo, resiway]) => {
  // ...
  // await for all loop at once to avoid odd side effects
  await Promise.all(resiway.value.data.result.map(async function (item) {
    // ...
    arrcars = {};
    arrcars["price_client"] = await 
  forexService.convertCurrency(item.price, "EUR", userCurrency);
    arrcars["discountprice_client"] = await 
  forexService.convertCurrency(item.price, "EUR", userCurrency);
    // ...
  }));
  // ...
});
```

Comment: I tried your second option but i get this error.

               await Promise.all(resiway.value.data.result.map(async function (item) {
                ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: and if i use first option, then in whole result, i get blank object.

Comment: After update i am getting this error.

error: TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
    at Function.all (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/src/controllers/cars.controller.js:135:31
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)

Comment: I have no idea what can cause it

Comment: i am checking. atleast i have learned how to use async/await, thank you for that

Comment: i think, what we are passing inside promise.all is going as undefined. 
but when i remove promise.all then this error is gone.

Comment: Oh Sorry ! it was my bad, i was still using "forEach" instead of "map". i didn't notice map in your answer initially.

Comment: But problem with result is, for each provider, like talixo and iway, i am getting same result. like if iway returns 5 result and talixo returned 3 result, then all those 5 from iway have same value and all 3 from talixo have same result.

Answer (score 1):

**simplify your services**

You are writing the Talixo and Iway services but using the result is difficult. Instead of returning the entire response, return the fields that matter to your consumer -

```js
// services/talixo_service.js

async function findTalixoCars(query) {
  const result = await // ... perform request
  return result.value.data ?? [] // <- return relevant data
}
```

Notice we use `return _____ ?? []` to ensure that an array is *always* returned -

```js
// services/iway_service.js

async function findiWayCars(query) {
  const result = await // ... perform request
  return result.value.data.result ?? [] // <- return relevant data
}
```

**searchCars**

With simplified services, we write a high-level implementation of `searchCars`. Instead of using `Promise.allSettled` we can use `.catch(_ => [])` on potential failures to guarantee we have an array result. This reduces the need for logical checks and code branches to make the code more declarative and less prone to errors -

```js
async function searchCars(req, res) {
  const [talixo, iway] = await Promise.all([
    talixoService.findTalixoCars(req.body).catch(_ => []),
    iwayService.findiWayCars(req.body).catch(_ => [])
  ])

  const userCurrency = req.query.usercurrency ?? "INR"

  const taxis = [
    ...await Promise.all(talixo.taxis.map(item => fromTalixo(item, userCurrency))),
    ...await Promise.all(talixo.limousines.map(item => fromTalixo(item, userCurrency))),
    ...await Promise.all(iway.map(item => fromIway(item, userCurrency)))
  ]
  
  res.status(200).send(
    taxis.sort((a,b) => a.discountprice - b.discountprice)
  )
}
```

**data mapping**

The search function above depends on `fromTalixo` and `fromIway`. These mapping functions reduce code complexity and repitition and gives us a good conceptual model for how data gets mapped from the remote services to our local data -

```js
async function fromTalixo(data, userCurrency) {
  return {
    carname: data.car_model,
    originprice: data.regular_price,
    price_client: await forexService.convertCurrency(data.regular_price, "EUR", userCurrency),
    discountprice_client: await forexService.convertCurrency(data.discount_price, "EUR", userCurrency),
    packageId: data.id,
    image: data.image_url,
    freewaittime: data.included_waiting_time,
    maxluggage: data.luggage,
    maxpassengers: data.seats,
    discountprice: data.discount_price,
    vehicletype: data.vehicle_type,
    vendor: "Talixo",
    vehicleremarks: "Or Similar",
  }
}
```

```js
async function fromIway(data, userCurrency) {
  return {
    carname: data.car_class.models[0],
    originprice: data.price,
    price_client: await forexService.convertCurrency(data.price, "EUR", userCurrency),
    discountprice_client: await forexService.convertCurrency(data.price, "EUR", userCurrency),
    packageId: data.price_uid,
    image: `https://iwayex.com/images/cars/${data.car_class.photo}`,
    freewaittime: data.allowable_time,
    maxluggage: "",
    maxpassengers: data.car_class.capacity,
    discountprice: data.price,
    vehicletype: data.vehicle_type,
    vendor: "iway Transfers",
    vehicleremarks: "Or Similar",
  }
}
```

Comment: very clean code ! thanks for explaining me this.  learnt more today. just edited few typos in your code.

Comment: thanks for catching those. happy to assist :D

Comment: Hi, One more issue, i face with your code is, if talixo return blank result, like when i print talixo, in some searches it return "[]" . then i get this issue - error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.. How to solve such issues here.

Comment: if talixo (or any service) returns a null or empty result, you should return `[]` instead, which means there is a zero list of cars. That would look like `return result.value.data ?? []`. Because all arrays have map method, the TypeError will go away. I updated the post to reflect this change.